# Prepare and Execute Query Stored in a Table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, plpgsql

I want to `PREPARE` the query inside `query_string` and `EXECUTE` it. `query_string` can also be stored as a field in a `temp` table.

```
select concat('insert into some_table select ', 
       string_agg(concat('NEW.', column_name), ', ')) as query_string
from information_schema.columns
where table_catalog = 'database_name'
  and table_schema = 'schema_name'
  and table_name ='table_name';
```

Doing this to use this query inside a Trigger. I don't want to change the Trigger Definition when the structure of the table changes. As PostgreSQL currently doesn't support DDL triggers, I don't think that there's any other way of coming around this.

Comment: Postgres does support DDL triggers: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-trigger-matrix.html

Comment: That looks vulnerable to SQL injection.